# Sql utilizando left join

Tags: sql, firebird, inner-join

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
TB_ESTOQUE
|PRODUTO|QT_DISPONIVEL|COD_FILIAL|
|0856322|      5      |    41    |
|0856351|      2      |    41    |
|0856322|      9      |    114   |
|0856720|      3      |    20    |

TB_FILIAL
|COD_FILIAL|COD_LOCALADM| 
|    41    |    114     |
|    128   |    114     |
|    133   |    114     |
|    10    |    156     |
|    56    |     12     |
```

Resultado desejado:

```
|COD_FILIAL|  ESTOQUE_FILIAL  |
|    41    |     41 - 2       |
|    128   |128 - SEM ESTOQUE |
|    133   |133 - SEM ESTOQUE |
```

Estou tentando fazer o SQL dessa forma:

```
SELECT
F.COD_FILIAL,
CASE WHEN E.QT_DISPONIVEL IS NULL THEN
  F.COD_FILIAL || ' - ' || 'SEM ESTOQUE'
ELSE F.COD_FILIAL || ' - ' || E.QT_DISPONIVEL
END AS ESTOQUE_FILIAL
FROM
TB_FILIAL F
LEFT JOIN TB_ESTOQUE E
ON E.COD_FILIAL = F.COD_FILIAL AND  E.COD_PRODUTO = 0856351 AND
F.COD_LOCALADM = 114
ORDER BY
E.COD_FILIAL
```

O SQL esta me retornando todos os registros da tabela `TB_ESTOQUE`. Ignorando o comando

```
"F.COD_LOCALADM = 114"
```

Comment: Retire o F.COD_LOCALADM = 114 do LEFT JOIN com a tabela TB_ESTOQUE e coloque num WHERE logo abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `ON` no `LEFT JOIN` funciona para as chaves que você quer manter no seu `JOIN`, para adicionar condições você precisa de um `WHERE`, como em:

```
SELECT
F.COD_FILIAL,
CASE WHEN E.QT_DISPONIVEL IS NULL THEN
F.COD_FILIAL || ' - ' || 'SEM ESTOQUE'
ELSE F.COD_FILIAL || ' - ' || E.QT_DISPONIVEL
END AS ESTOQUE_FILIAL
FROM
TB_FILIAL F
LEFT JOIN TB_ESTOQUE E
ON E.COD_FILIAL = F.COD_FILIAL 
WHERE E.COD_PRODUTO = 0856351 AND
F.COD_LOCALADM = 114
ORDER BY
E.COD_FILIAL
```